# How to hide column in JasperReports at runtime?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating one jasper report by connecting it with database. In which I have to hide table column depending upon the data I get after executing the query. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth investigating the Column Manager add-on available for Jasper Reports, which is described here: http://www.jaspersoft.com/add-ons

This "extends JasperReports to hide or show columns or groups of columns in a report based on user input or other parameters."